# How can I get this CSS to display properly in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

So I don't have to post too much code the page is:  http://www.ketchikanvet.com .  The problem is I can't get the tabs to be attached to the pane in IE8.  The majority of the vets clients use IE8 apparently so this is making it a pain in the ass for me.  Anyone know why?  CSS is:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #17BFEE;
    color: #111111;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: #111111;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #efefef;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#content {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}

/* root element for tabs  */
ul.tabs {  
    margin:0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:30px;
}

/* single tab */
ul.tabs li {  
    float:left;  
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;  
    list-style-type:none;   
}

/* link inside the tab. uses a background image */
ul.tabs a { 
    float:left;
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px 30px;   
    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px solid #001401;   
    border-bottom:0px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#000;
    margin-right:2px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        position:relative;  
    outline:0;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;  
}

ul.tabs a:hover {
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:#000;
}

/* selected tab */
ul.tabs a.current {
    background-color:#F0F0FF;
    border-bottom:2px solid #F0F0FF;    
    color:#000; 
    cursor:default;
}


/* tab pane */
.panes div {
    display:none;
    border:2px solid #001401;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:15px 20px;
    background-color:#F0F0FF;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #C4C4C4; 
}

/*End of Tabs*/

#gallery img {
    border: 2px solid #001401;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#gallery img:hover {
    border: 2px solid #494949;
}

#footer a {
    color: #111111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #efefef;
}

#addhours {
    width: 100%;
}

#addhours td {
    width: 50%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #890224;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #890224;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #890224;
}

.falselink {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bioimage {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #C4C4C4;
    border: 2px solid #001401;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.photo {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #C4C4C4;
    border: 2px solid #001401;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#browsercheck {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to UL.tabs A

```
border-bottom-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:2px;
```

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything.  Just added it and tested in IE8.  Still has a gap between the tabs and the pane.

Comment: Nevermind.  Changed it to:  border-bottom-xxxx and it worked just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: oops... sorry about that, it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I added a height of 32px to your anchors inside the ul.tabs and it seemed to be what you're looking for.

```
ul.tabs a {height:32px;}
```

If you're using the html5 boiler plate you can target ie alone.

```
.ie8 ul.tabs a {height:32px;}
```